# How to access already running process in linux terminal?

Tags: c, linux, gdb

I am using gdb to debug my program. say `a.out`
Now gdb is running as `gdb ./a.out`
By mistake, I pressed Ctrl+z to exit instead of q.
I used ps -eaf and got to know gdb is running with the program in the background with an id 15269.

I want to access this same process instead of typing `gdb ./a.out` once again.

I tried over google but couldn't find anything except `fg %[process_number]` which just told me that no such job exists.

Can you please help?

Thanks

Comment: Just start again your debug session (which you might run from `emacs`). It is faster than waiting some answer here.

Answer (score 2):

type `fg` to get back to the background process in that shell...

Answer (score 2):

1- In Terminal write `$ jobs`.
2- the Terminal will list the running jobs with a number of each job.
3- use `$ fg %x` as x= number of the job.

Comment: It is not running as a job but running as a process with a pid:15269

Comment: when I do jobs, nothing is coming up

Comment: but when I do, ps -eaf , the process is still running.

Comment: it's because you close the terminal, i think the only way now is to kill the process and execute it again